# Disable trigger in production. What are the consequences?

Tags: trigger, production

The salesforce documentation says:

> **How do I disable a Trigger in a production environment?**
>
> You must consider the consequences of disabling a trigger in the
>   production environment during work hours. It is highly recommended to
>   perform this during off-hours. Also, disable access to the application
>   to non administrators during the maintenance period.

**Question**

- What are the consequences of disabling a trigger in the production environment that are mentioned in the documentation?
- Are there different consequences in a production than a sandbox org?

Comment: The consequences of disabling X, are ... unsuprisingly... that X does not work anymore, the downstream consequences of that are whatever might depend on X working could be affected.

Comment: Hi Brad. You are right that it depends on what the functionality is. But from a business point of view you want to know what are all the potential risks so that you can mitigate all the risks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I talked to salesforce Support the support wrote:

> 1. During work hours, large no of users try to access the data, if you will disable the trigger and trigger were related of any of the events
>      then the functionality stop working in production. Functionality like
>      update the field, send an email, create a new record etc. which are
>      executed by this trigger, all those functionalities is not working in
>      production.
> 2. If any batch will be scheduled for a specific time for insert/update/delete functionality and if the trigger was related any
>      of the functionality, stop working in production and might be its
>      cause the error.
> 3. After disabling the trigger your functionality like, update the field, send an email, create a new record etc will not work. So might
>      be It's affected your scheduled reports.
> 4. If the trigger is calling from another trigger handler class so after disabling the trigger its cause the error in a production
>      environment.
>
> **Consideration:**
>
> - Please check the functionality of trigger.
> - Please check the batch jobs which is related this trigger also please check all the dependencies of the trigger.
> - Please try to perform this functionality during off-hours because no of users is less and the probability of hitting any issues would be
>     less.
> - Please create a debug logs after disabling the trigger, so you can easily find the error if its occurs.

Answer (score 7):

The consequences can be anything depending upon the business logic written in the trigger. For example -

1. if a business logic is supposed to update fields, the updates will fail
2. If the business logic is supposed to call a different system and get the data in Salesforce, it would fail.
3. If business logic is supposed to send email, it might fail.

Bottomline : Any business logic written inside the trigger will not execute. The best practice would be to analyze the underlying logic and find out the impact. Infact disable the trigger in sandbox first to understand the impact.